# Срабатывание скрипта только при редактировании определенной колонки

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

```
function SpecialOnEdit(e) {

  /*var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var R = cell.getRow(); // записывается ROW*/
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var R = e.range.getRow();
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = ss.getRange(R, 3, 7, R).getValues();
  var c = 0;
  for (var c = values[0].length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
    if (values[0][c] != "") break;
  }

  values[0].splice(c + 1, values[0].length - c - 1);

  var valuesRow = values[0];

  if (valuesRow[6] == "Quick Formatted" || valuesRow[6] ==
    "No Bad Sectors Good" || valuesRow[6] == "Good Working" || valuesRow[6] ==
    "Bad Sectors") {

    if (sheetName == "335710") {
      var result = false;

      if (result === false) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Task started for row ' + R,
          'Result', 3);
      }

      //call function to get data from donordrives 
      result = requestToDonordrives(valuesRow);
      sheet.getRange(R, idCol = 8).setValue(result).toString();
    }
  }
}
```

у меня есть данный код.

Он работает отлично. Но как сделать так, чтобы он срабатывал только тогда, когда редактируется столбец I?

Может подскажете функцию которая может это отследить? Ничего не смог найти в интернете!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое, что можно сделать - это проверить, к какой колонке пигадлежит диапазон при котором сработал триггер:

```
function SpecialOnEdit(e) {
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if(col !== 9 || col !== e.range.getLastColumn()){
    SpreadsheetApp.toast('Не та колонка');
    return;
  }
...
```